# "Unresolved reference: etName" in android studio with kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was working on an Android Project in Kotlin, and I got an error in this code:

```kotlin
 val btnSignUp: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp)

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener{
            val userName = etName.text.toString()
            val email = etEmail.text.toString()
            val password = etPassword.text.toString()
            val confirmPassword = etConfirmPassword.text.toString()

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"username is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            ......
```

```kotlin
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@color/colorTextBackground"
            android:hint="@string/enter_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@color/colorTextBackground"
            android:hint="@string/enter_email"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@color/colorTextBackground"
            android:hint="@string/enter_password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@color/colorTextBackground"
            android:hint="@string/enter_confirm_password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText" />
```

The second part of code is what `etname`, `etPassword` and `etConfirmPassword` define in xml file.

The error is `Unresolved reference:` etName`

The same error is occurring for `etPassword` and `etConfirmPassword`.
I can post more code if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your question and make the code a [mcve]? We need to be able to reproduce the problem to help you.

Comment: Post more code please. Show us the part of your code where you have defined `etName` and others.

Comment: is etName id of the EditText defined in the layout.xml file? If you are using the latest version of all the tools then you should learn View Binding. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kotlin

Comment: Yes, I am using etName id of the EditText defined in the layout.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `etName`, `etEmail` and others have been defined in **XML Layout** files, so you *cannot* use them in your Kotlin code as they are. First, store them in a variable through your `R` file like this:

```
val etName: EditText = findViewById(R.id.etName)
val etEmail: EditText = findViewById(R.id.etEmail)
val etPassword: EditText = findViewById(R.id.etPassword)
val etConfirmPassword: EditText = findViewById(R.id.etConfirmPassword)
```

You can also use **View Binding** by following the link given in the comments.
Now, you can use your variables, without any problem.

Comment: You can upvote the answer and mark it as accepted to express your gratitude. You're welcome!